# This error frequently occurs can you tell the reason why this error occur

Tags: xquery

this is my code:

```
let $lib := doc($document)/INVOICES
let $a :=  for $b in $lib/invoices
return $a
```

Comment: You should show the error that occurs. Your question is unclear

Comment: expected "return", found "<eof>"

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement is nested inside a let statement, so the overall query has no return statement, which is what the error message is telling you.

you second let statement makes no sense, try the below:

```
let $lib := doc($document)/INVOICES 
let $a := for $b in $lib/invoices return $b

return
  $a
```